# C# string to array from readline issue

Tags: c#, arrays

I am doing some C# exercises, the assignment is to check if att Swedish SSN is issued to a woman or a man.

The algorithm checks if the ninth number is equally dividable by 0, then it's a woman or else a man.

If I use a hardcoded "nr" in a string variable, the algorithm works, but if I try to read it from a readline statement, I get the following error:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: startIndex

This is the code I am using:

```cs
//string personnr = "860215-2097";
string personnr = "";
char[] arr;
    
public void CheckGender(string pnr)
{
    arr = personnr.ToCharArray(9, 1);
    
    if (personnr[9] %2 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Woman!!!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Man!!!");
    }
}
    
public void PrintPersonNr()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Write a personnr in the format yymmdd-nnnn: ");
    string nr = Console.ReadLine();
    CheckGender(nr);
}
```

So it's my `PrintPersonNr` method that's not working properly I guess..

Comment: You don't check, that `pnr` is long enough. Besides that, your code only works by luck, since you are not checking whether the 9th digit is devisible by 2, but whether the char code is devisible by 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
public enum SSNGender
{
  Female,
  Male
}

class Program
{

  static public Dictionary<SSNGender, string> SSNGenderText
    = new Dictionary<SSNGender, string>()
  {
    { SSNGender.Female, "Woman" },
    { SSNGender.Male, "Man" },
  };

  static public SSNGender CheckSSNGender(string pnr)
  {
    // Here check the validity of the pnr (length, format...)
    return pnr[9] % 2 == 0 ? SSNGender.Female : SSNGender.Male;
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Write a personnr in the format yymmdd-nnnn: ");
    string nr = Console.ReadLine();
    var result = CheckSSNGender(nr);
    Console.WriteLine(SSNGenderText[result]);
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
```

Comment: I haven't yet come upon Dictionary, but I do understand the code though, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
        public void CheckGender(string pnr)
        {
            string arr = pnr.Substring(10, 1);

            if (arr == "0")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Woman!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Man!!!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Found that: "Usage of the Swedish Social Security Number. The gender is indicated by the third digit, even for women, odd for men."

Comment: Yes, but that's after the birtydate, so if I have a separator char as '-' then it should be the ninth char.

Comment: @jdweng, that sure does work, but I have to solve this with a array

Comment: Are you sure the assignments says the checking needs to be done using ARRAYS?  It is not standard in c# to use arrays with strings.  That is why microsoft created the method SubString().

Comment: Changed index from 9 to 10.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to use the modulus operator and then to check if this number is then divisible by two and if the result is zero then it is even.

There is a fundamental issue as well, you would need to check if the character is a number or not. if it is then the operation would need to then be completed, if not you need to let the user know.

I have modified [JDWeng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng) post

```
public void CheckGender(string pnr)
{
    string arr = pnr.Substring(9, 1);
    int num =0;

    if (int.TryParse(arr, num))
    {
        if ((num % 2) == "0")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Man!!!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Woman!!!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not a number!");
    }
}
```

Best of luck in your exercise as well!!!

Comment: thanks, I am getting two errors, this in the if statement
Argument 2 must be passed with the 'out' keyword 
Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'